# True or false: $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left((x \mod 5)+\frac{1}{x+1} \right )=5$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

I'm not really sure because

$(x \mod 5) \leq4$

$\Rightarrow$

$4+\frac{1}{0+1}=4+1=5$

The statement would  be true but we also need to know that it could be lower than $5$...

Im confused if statement is true or false now.

I think statement wrong then because limes sup goes to $\infty$ so modulo won't be 4, it will be very very close to 4. So final result will be almost 5 but not exactly (it will be lower)?

Comment: $\limsup_{x \to \infty}$ only cares about _large values_ of $x$. What happens to $\frac{1}{x+1}$ when $x$ becomes large?

Comment: Hint: consider the limit points of your sequence. The $\limsup$ is equal to the largest limit point.

Comment: Oh it will be small the denominator so complete result will be very big.. So no need to care about modulo because we already know result bigger than 5, much bigger.

Comment: The other way around, $1/(x+1)$ gets very small as $x$ gets large.

Comment: The answer is $4$ because $\frac{1}{x+1}$ tends to $0$.

Comment: What is $4.9\mod{5}$; what about $499.99999\mod{5}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take $x_n=5n-\frac{1}{n}$ and calculate the limit for this sequence.

Comment: What does $5n$ have to do with anything?

Comment: @Arthur $x_n\to\infty$. Calculate $x_n\mod{5}$.